WKHTMLTOPDF SSL Issues on Heroku
Has anyone had any success in installing wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 or higher on Heroku?
I've successfully managed to get the wkhtmltopdf buildpack installed using the following: https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack.
Using the command line I've tested this out using the following command:
/app/bin/wkhtmltopdf "https://www.google.com" test.pdf

Installed WKHTMLTOPDF version is: 0.12.3
I'm able to generate documents over HTTP, however soon as I attempt to call any URLs with HTTPS domains then I get the following QSslSocket errors:
Loading pages (1/6)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks                  ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_peer_certificate
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
Error: Failed loading page https://www.google.com (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback

Looking over the WKHTMLToPDF Github repo and issues this seems to be an issue for older versions of WKHTMLTOPDF
I've tried a host of different buildpacks tonight which don't seem to deployable on the Heroku 24 stack.
Kind of ran out of ideas of how to generate pdfs via python unless I look at a third party API service which will mean a fairly significant rewrite of logic I've been working on.
